# mongoDB collection not getting updated with latest data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am making some API calls to fetch data form the server and want to store it in mongoDB. Data that I am getting from remote server may or may not contain duplicate data. Whenever I am getting duplicate data my code working well and it is not stored in the database but when i am getting new data this is where my code fails and it is not stored in the database.

In the below code snippet I am disconnecting mongoose from mongoDB when data is stored in the database. When I remove this line of code it is working as intended. But I read it is good practice to disconnect from DB.

```
function MongoEDBedListStore (edBedList) {
  try {
    return edBedList.map((bedListRow) => {
      return EDBedList.findOneAndUpdate(
        { mrn: bedListRow.mrn, eventType: bedListRow.eventType },
        bedListRow,
        { upsert: true, new: true }
      )
      .exec()
      .then(() => console.log('ED Bed List Added'))
      .then(() => mongoose.disconnect())  //works well if i remove this line
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        mongoose.disconnect();
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Can someone please let me know if it is good to remove disconnect logic or there is any other way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a synchronous map and then disconnecting as soon as the first document completes.

If you want to use promises, I think it should instead look something like:

```js
const updatePs = beds.map((bed) => BedList.findOneAndUpdate(...));
Promise.all(updatePs).then(() => "it'd be OK to disconnect here");
```

Bluebird can make code like this a bit cleaner (as can using async/await).

As far as disconnecting/not disconnecting goes, it's going to depend on your use-case. If you've got a server that handles requests, it's generally best to keep the connection open. If it's a one-time job, it's best to close the connection after you're done.

Comment: I will be doing this operation every 2 mins. So i guess it is good to keep connection open??

Comment: You should definitely keep the connection open. Disconnect only when the process(node) needs to exit